# Raspberry Pi different ip addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, iot

The following problem:
I am having a Raspi3B+ running home assistant.
Now, I have the Pi configured to connect via WLAN. However, in my router I see two ip addresses: a LAN one and a WLAN one.

1. Can I disable the LAN IP somehow? There is no cable plugged into the ethernet port, yet it shows it as online?
2. The WLAN ip changes every time I reboot the pi. Should I set it to static on the router, or should that be done on the pi itself - if so, where?

I basically want the Pi to only show up on my router with one IP address that always stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

A router's detection of a client can sometimes be delayed or buggy. The ethernet interface of the Pi should disappear from the router's client list after it's been disconnected for some time, and if it does not, then a reboot of the router should correct that issue. It's not a problem for it to simply be listed, but I understand your frustration with it still showing while disconnected.

You can set the static IP for the Pi on the router or the Pi. If set on the Pi's end, the Pi will not request an IP address from your router and will force its interface to use the IP you specify. If you set it on the router's end, the Pi will still request a dynamic IP from the router using DHCP. But, the router will always assign the Pi the same IP address that you set. It's up to you how you wish to deal with it.

Without knowing your router model, I can't provide you with specific instructions on how to set a device's IP address, but most routers have a "DHCP Reservation" option that you will want to set. As for setting it from the Pi itself, that can vary too, but what it comes down to is that you need to follow the [instructions for the OS you are running](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/tcpip/), which I assume is Raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

**Can I disable the LAN IP?**
You could [disable the ethernet interface on the Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23487728/1256347) but I don't think it's necessary.
If you really want to make that entry disappear from your router, the easiest way is to reset the router (unplug from power for 30 seconds).

**How to set a fixed WLAN IP**
If your router supports it, this can be done in your router. Look for "*DHCP binding*" in the router settings, or do a websearch for "*<your router brand and type> dhcp binding*" to find how to configure your router.
DHCP binding allows you to bind a MAC address (which is unique for a networking interface) to a certain IP address.